# Проблема с работой Django в Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-model, venv

Неделю назад по непонятной причине во всех проектах Django (даже самых старых, которые по полгода не открывались), запускаемых в pycharm, стала выскакивать одна и та же ошибка (скрин ниже).
Возникает она в двух ситуациях, которые, с точки зрения действия среды разработки, довольно похожи:

1. при попытке импортировать в python shell модели Django - повторюсь, это происходит именно тогда, когда python shell запущен в Pycharm. Если его запускать через GitBash, то никаких ошибок нет.
2. при использовании функции apps.get_model('имя модели из уже ранее созданных'). Абсолютно та же самая ошибка, что и в случае выше.
   [image: начало сообщения]
   [image: продолжение сообщения]

Один знакомый опытный разработчик как раз и посоветовал запустить python shell через git bash. И когда там все сработало, то появился единственный логичный вывод - это что-то с pycharm, если уж эта ошибка возникает даже в старых черновых проектах Django, где кода - полторы строчки.
Этот же разработчик сказал, что ошибка возникает из-за того, что pycharm запускает python shell вместо django shell. Но нагуглить решения этой проблемы не получилось. Обновление pycharm до последней версии не помогло.
Прошу помощи, т.к. из-за этой ошибки стоит работа над проектом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Pycharm в верхнем меню нажмите run, далее Edit Configuration. Найдите Environment variables, нажмите справа для редактирования и добавления новых переменных, добавьте туда данные где name: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, а value: `project_name.settings`где project_name имя вашего проекта, а settings ваш файл settings.py. Далее сохраните изменения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло решить ситуацию)

Comment: Не за что, рад был вам помочь.